# Getting "mkdir: cannot create directory..." while installing & using NVM/Node.js commands

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nvm

I have a freshly installed 14.04 LTS version of Ubuntu Linux, onto which I recently installed NVM & Node.js. I did so by entering the next two commands into my terminal following these [instructions](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.7.0/install.sh | sh`
`nvm install 0.10`

Awesome, I have NVM & Node installed! Running commands like `nvm ls` provides me with a listing of versions that have been installed and so on...So? well, the problem is that after restarting my computer/logging out.. I'm getting:

```
ricardo:~$ nvm ls
    sbin
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/sbin/alias’: Permission denied
```

I'm getting similar messages with other commands, for example:

```
ricardo:~$ nvm use 0.10
 N/A version is not installed yet
ricardo:~$ nvm deactivate
 Could not find /usr/sbin/*/bin in $PATH
 Could not find /usr/sbin/*/share/man in $MANPATH
 Could not find /usr/sbin/*/lib/node_modules in $NODE_PATH
```

When I go into my ~/.nvm/ directory, I see that the version of Node I had installed is still present, how can I fix this?

Comment: You can follow the actual discussion [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/433)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I just had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04, fixed it by providing $NVM_DIR before sourcing nvm.sh, like so:

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
. .nvm/nvm.sh
```

After that, all nvm commands seem to work again.

Comment: Pure genius. In case you are still getting the "Permission denied" error try running: `source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh` also